# Consumer kafka java code is running without output

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-kafka

i am trying to run a kafka consumer program in order to get messages from topic named "test2"

i am using Kafka 0.9 API

```
Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
     props.put("group.id", "test");
     props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
     props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
     props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
     props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test2"));
     while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
             System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
     }
    }
```

this code is from the official documentation of the Kafka Consumer API 0.9

the figure below clarify more the situation

[Eclipse console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSFwH.png)

Any suggestions for resolving this issue

Thank you in advance

Comment: This suggests that there are no new messages arriving. Try setting `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`, change your `group.id` to something else and see what happens.

Comment: @ftr thanks i already tried this option but in vain

Answer (score 0):

Just add slf4j jar in your build path and try